# Color Cells in a Worksheet Based on Data From Another Worksheet in Same Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have the following worksheet called **Data**:
[image]

In the same workbook I have another worksheet called **Employee Database**.
[image]

In Excel, how can I color the "Employee E-mail Address" and the corresponding "Company" and "Company URL" cells red from the **Data** worksheet if the "Employee E-mail Address" is not in the **Employee Database**?

In otherwords, I am trying to make the **Employee Database** worksheet look like this:
[image]

I've just given an example and in reality I have over 10,000 cells worth of data to do this to. I started doing this manually and realized it will take me forever.

I'd love to know if there is a macro that can do this in Excel?

Help would be so much appreciated! I have the example workbook of the screenshots above available for download here:
http://www.mediafire.com/?dttztp66dvjkzn8

Comment: Yes you can write a macro to check. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yeah, I've used CTRL+F to search for e-mail addresses and if Excel tells me no matches found, I highlight them red. The problem is that's taking a really long time. After an hour, I've searched for a little over 100. I have over 10,000 cells to check, so at my current rate it's going to take me a few days of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? This will create a new sheet "Desired Result" with the output. Paste this in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsDB As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim clrRng As Range

    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    Set wsDB = Sheets("Employee Database")
    Set wsO = Sheets.Add

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Desired Result").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    With wsO
        .Name = "Desired Result"
        wsData.Cells.Copy .Cells

        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value
        Next i

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsDB.Columns(3), .Range("A" & i).Value) = 0 Then
                If clrRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set clrRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set clrRng = Union(clrRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not clrRng Is Nothing Then clrRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then .Range("A" & i).ClearContents
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG it worked!!! yessss!!! you just literally saved me DAYS worth of find and replace! thank yo so very, very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without VBA, but it will require a slight change to the data on your `Data` sheet.

I don't recommend the "Pivot Table" or "Subtotal"-style of data storage in Excel, where you enter a primary key in one column *only once* then fill down associated data next to it until the next primary key.

Like merged cells, this will only lead to problems later when you want to re-organize your data.

Here's what I did:

### Fill in missing email addresses on Data sheet

Highlight cells `A2` all the way down column `A` to the end of the data in column **B**. So if you had company names in cells `B2:B100`, but only had emails from `A2:A98`, you should highlight `A2:A100`. This is because we are filling in the email address in each row of available data.

Go to **Editing** » **Find & Select** » **Go To Special**, select `Blanks` and click `OK`.

[image: go to special, blanks]

Now with blanks selected, type `=` <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow) , then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The blank cells in column A will fill in with the missing email addresses. Highlight column A, copy and paste values.

### Create Dynamic Named Range for Emails

On the `Employee Database` sheet, create a named range called "Emails" with the following formula in the "Refers to" box:

`=OFFSET('Employee Database'!$C$1,1,0,COUNTA('Employee Database'!$C:$C)-1,1)`

### Add Conditional Formatting

On the `Data` sheet, highlight `A2:C whatever` (ex: `A2:C20000`), then go to **Home** » **Styles** » **Conditional Formatting** and use the following formula:

`=ISNA(MATCH($A2,Emails,0))`

Select the color scheme you want and click `OK`. Here's how it looks on my computer with some sample data:

[image: highlight sample data not found]

There are a few minor constraints:

- You cannot leave column A blank on the `Data` sheet any more.
- You cannot have blank rows on the `Employee Database` sheet in between rows of data. This is due to the way the dynamic range works.

### Benefits

The benefits of this approach are, IMO, huge.

- You can add or remove rows from the Employee Database sheet, and the highlighting will automatically adjust. Ex: if I add d@gmail.com and remove c@nbc.com, the formatting on the `Data` sheet updates immediately.

[image: updated employee database]

- You don't have to alter your existing worksheet structure (other than filling in the missing data and adding a range name). No need for additional worksheets.
- Your workbook can stay VBA-free (if it didn't have any already).